# How to avoid 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I tried to run the following code in both Firefox and Chrome, it gets run in Firefox but in Chrome: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

```
const list = new Array(60000).join('1.1').split('.');

function removeItemsFromList() {
    var item = list.pop();

    if (item) {
        removeItemsFromList();
    }
};

removeItemsFromList();
```

Is there any way to prevent it and make it run in all the browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to avoid the error would be to make the recursive call only after a `Promise.resolve`:

```js
const list = new Array(60000).join('1.1').split('.');

function removeItemsFromList() {
    var item = list.pop();

    if (item) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(removeItemsFromList);
    }
};

removeItemsFromList()
  .then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

If you want to do it with `setTimeout` instead of Promises, put the recursive call in a `setTimeout` only if the current stack size is too large:

```js
const list = new Array(60000).join('1.1').split('.');
let i = 0;

function removeItemsFromList() {
  i++;
  var item = list.pop();
  if (!item) {
    console.log('Done');
    return;
  }
  if (i > 5000) {
    i = 0;
    setTimeout(removeItemsFromList);
  } else {
    removeItemsFromList();
  }
};

removeItemsFromList();
```

Comment: I was going through a coding challenge and stuck here. Is there any way to make it run using setTimeout()?

Comment: Problem with `setTimeout` is that it's a macrotask, not a microtask, and iterating through 60k macrotasks will take a while. But I guess you could check the current stack size, and create a new stack only if the old one is too large

Answer (score 2):

What about a non recursive version ?

```
const list = new Array(60000).join('1.1').split('.');

function removeItemsFromList() {
    var item = list.pop();

    while (item) {
        item = list.pop();
    }
};

removeItemsFromList();
```

Here are some numbers on maximum callstack allowed ([source](https://2ality.com/2014/04/call-stack-size.html)):

> Node.js: 11034
>   Firefox: 50994
>   Chrome: 10402

Comment: Nice thought! But I just wanted to overcome that error. Thanks for the another way!

Answer (score 1):

You are reaching the max stack size because you are calling removeItem recursively, an alternate solution can be:

```
function removeItemsFromList() {
   while(list.length > 0){
      list.pop();   
   }
};

removeItemsFromList();
```